# Why is findAll() not returning all objects in model?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sequelize.js

Im working on mocking DB because im unit testing API. For mocking i use sequelize-mock library and for models i use sequelize. When im calling GET request the function getAll() returns only first element in that array.

My mock model:

```
const assetmeter = (sequelize) => {
  const AssetMeter = sequelize.define('assetmeter', {
    id: 1,
    assetId: 1,
    sequence: null,
    meterName: 'BAD',
    measureUnit: 'km',
    meterType: 'CHARACTERISTIC', 
    description: 'test description', 
    active: true,
  },{
    id: 2,
    assetId: 2,
    sequence: null,
    meterName: 'TEST',
    measureUnit: 'TEST',
    meterType: 'TEST', 
    description: 'TEST', 
    active: true,
  });

  return AssetMeter;
}

module.exports = assetmeter;
```

Get all function:

```
import { AssetMeter } from '../../models';
import paginate from '../../utils/paginate';

export default async (req, res) => {
  let assetMeters = [];
  try {
    assetMeters = await AssetMeter.findAndCountAll({
      limit: req.pagination.limit, 
      offset: req.pagination.offset
    });
    console.log(assetMeters);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).send({ error: 'Internal server error' });
  }
  const links = paginate(req.protocol, req.hostname, req.baseUrl, req.pagination, assetMeters.count);
  if (links) {
    res.set('Link', links);
  }
  return res.set('X-Total-Count', assetMeters.count).send(assetMeters.rows);
};
```

The output im expecting is that it would return two objects in array.
Current result:

```
[ { id: 1,
    assetId: 1,
    sequence: null,
    meterName: 'BAD',
    measureUnit: 'km',
    meterType: 'CHARACTERISTIC',
    description: 'test description',
    active: true,
    createdAt: '2019-03-29T07:33:02.812Z',
    updatedAt: '2019-03-29T07:33:02.812Z' } ]
```

Comment: What is the value of `req.pagination.limit` and `req.pagination.offset`?

Comment: @bird Value for pagination is 100, offset is 0

Comment: please share sql command generated from findAndCountAll. add option "log: console.log" just like limit offset options.

Comment: @RohitDalal i didn't get nothing, sequelize doesn't have this feature i think

Comment: Log will be made in your terminal of sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that's the expected output, I think you're using `define` the wrong way. There are 2 things.

First, the method signature is:

```
define(name, [obj={}], [opts]) -> Model
```

You are passing 3 arguments, but only the 2nd is valid. It is an object containing the default values for `AssetMeter`. Therefore the 3rd argument is ignored, because it's supposed to be `opts`.

Second, you're trying to populate your mock with many `AssetMeter` but for that you need to insert (create) them. Again, the second argument is the default values *for the properties* of `AssetMeter` (id, assetId, etc).

That's why your `findAll` returns only 1 result, it's an object with such default values.

I think the best way to do it if you want the 2 objects is to mock the query by using `$queueResults`:

```
const DEFAULT_VALUE: { /*...*/ };

const assetmeter = (sequelize) => {

  const AssetMeter = sequelize.define('assetmeter', DEFAULT_VALUE);

  AssetMeter.$queueResult([UserMock.build(), UserMock.build(), /* ... */]);

  return AssetMeter;
}

module.exports = assetmeter;
```

Take a look at the docs: https://sequelize-mock.readthedocs.io/en/stable/docs/mock-queries/#queued-results.

I hope this helps!